# App is crash in super dealloc method

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, crash-reports

My app is crashing on `[super dealloc];`  line and in `- (void)dealloc` method where I am releasing all object which retain in .h class, the crash report is

```
-[__NSArrayI respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x86fb1a0
-[__NSArrayI respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x86fb1a0
-[__NSArrayI respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x86fb970
-[UIButton release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x9b914b0
```

but what happend when I block `[super dealloc];` this line code works perfectly but it gives me warning `Method possibly missing [super dealloc] call`. If any one know kindly help me where I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

**Edited**

```
 [_gf_Knowledge_ratingStars release];
[_gf_Range_ratingStars release];
[_quality_ratingStars release];
[_atmosphere_ratingStars release];
[_reviewtxt release];
[_whatsGoodHere release];
[_saveButton release];
[_screen_title release];
[_commentImageView release];
[_resturantBGImageView release];
[_textViewPlaceholder release];
[_gFKnowledgeUnselectBtn release];
[_gFRangeUnselectBtn release];
[_gualityUnselectBtn release];
[_atmosphereUnselectBtn release];
[_gFKnowledgeLbl release];
[_gFRangeLbl release];
[_gualityLbl release];
[_atmosphereLbl release];
[_navbarImageView release];
[_btnBack release];
[super dealloc];
```

Comment: You overreleased something somewhere.

Comment: Are you releasing instances that are also released by super?

Comment: Its super class is UIViewController so I have no concern with UIViewController in this project, so I am doing nothing in super class.

Comment: Provide the code inside the dealloc method. Put an exceptional breakpoint you will get a bad access at some point.. you can easily fix that

Comment: I have spend many time on it, and it exactly getting crash on super dealloc line.

Comment: are you releasing button inside dealloc??

Comment: "holy mother of god" what are you releasing... please do not release  any UI component added on the controller's view (it not retained) in `dealloc`. 99% you are getting this crash on over releasing and for god's sake please turn ON NSZombie as well so that you might get a hook on the actual crash line!!

Comment: why are you releasing _gFKnowledgeUnselectBtn 3 times?

Comment: @samfisher If I'll release view controller's components in dealloc method, then where should I release these objects which I am retaining in .h class?

Comment: I have read in docs that viewdidunload is no longer used in iOS6, so if you want to assign nil to your objects then first find OS version if it is 6 then assign nil also in dealloc method after release.

Comment: @josh see my answer it may help you.

Comment: Can you comment out all the release statement in the dealloc method and see if the crash still occurs? I believe you are trying to release autoreleased arrays (see Dharmbir's answer). Can you post the lines where you are creating them?

Comment: Have you used the static analyzer to identify memory management problems in the project? Use the Product > Analyze menu item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are allocating the memory to  `NSArray` with `arrayWithArray` static method.

In this way it is getting added in the auto release pool and the retain count will be 0. Either retain it or manually `alloc` it with `[[NSArray alloc] init]`

Comment: Where to add auto release pool because I am releasing all those object in dealloc method whose I am retaining in .h class.

Comment: have you intialize your array in this way as i told you

Answer (score 2):

It can happen if you release an object twice. Please check all releases and remove any duplication.

Answer (score 1):

be sure to this line (`[super dealloc];`) is the last statement in `dealloc` method
I think you have written release for other class variables after `[super dealloc]`

Comment: Yes, this is the last statement in dealloc method.

Comment: Look at below Edited on my above Question.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are releasing the UI objects that are loaded as part of the NIB.

**Golden Rule**: Don't release anything you didn't allocate yourself.

Comment: I am assigning nil to all objects in - (void)viewDidUnload  method, actually this is default behaviour of xcode 4.5 when you make an auto outlets from nib to .h class.

Comment: @josh You need to provide more code to accurately answer your question.

Comment: Code is very simple, I have few outlets which is being retain in .h class and releasing in dealloc method and assigning nil in viewdidunload method and in whole class I am not creating or allocating and even not releasing any object. But note able thing is my Viewdidunload method is not being call, as I track this to put breakpoints.

Comment: @josh OK, I've edited my answer after you provided more code.

Comment: Of course, you could always switch to using ARC, and never have to worry about releasing or over-releasing again ...

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is one of the button you create as

```
UIButton* btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
```

and then you release in dealloc method. try to comment all button that declare as above.

Comment: The problem is related to arrays, the buttons seem OK.

Answer (score 0):

First enable zombie in your application

How to do it ?? Please go through this.

[How to enable NSZombie in Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386160/how-to-enable-nszombie-in-xcode)

now when your application crashes you will know for which line your application crashed. check what identifier does the object in question have. (retain or assign), check wether at some point along the line you have assigned an autorelease object to it, check whether you have used synthesized setters and getters to assign those values or assigning them straight to the property. if you have synthesized a property, you should always use the (.) dot operator to set and get values.

And as for the outlets that you have connected. Please check what identifier they have. (retain or assign).

Answer (score 0):

You have release any variable in two times and I think you have written release for other class variables after [super dealloc].